# Errors handling in resolve class angular2

Tags: angular, routes, resolve

I'm creating a resolve class in angular 2 based on Angular2 Docs, here is my class

```
//Angular core
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
//Service
import { CategoryService } from '../services/category.services';

//Model
import { Category } from '../model/category.interface';

@Injectable()
export class ListCategoryResolve implements Resolve<Category[]> {

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService, private router: Router) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,  state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<Category[]> {

     return this.categoryService.GetAll();

  }
}
```

How can I handle errors at this point?,if  for example my service is down

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,  state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<Category[]> {

     return this.categoryService.GetAll().catch(err => console.log(err));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In resolve method I need return a observable

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.categoryService.GetAll()     
      .catch(
      (err: Response, caught: Observable<Category[]>) => {
          if (err !== undefined) {
            this.router.navigate(["/error",{  outlet: 'error'}]);
            return Observable.throw('The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.');
          }
          return Observable.throw(caught); // <-----
        }
      ));
}
```

Comment: `));` should be `);`